# Are there still objections against the renormalizability of QED?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

I read that even Dirac in 1975 and Feynman in 1986 had concerns with the renormalizability of QED: [Renormalization.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization)

Which objections did they make? What is the present state concerning their objections?

Comment: If the objections were as simple as those quoted in the Wikipedia article, then the modern view that QED is merely an effective field theory understood to arise from a more fundamental theory already addresses these concerns.